# Como forçar a atualização do favicon.ico?

Tags: html, navegador-de-internet

Estou com um problema com o `favicon.ico`, ele aparece errado.

Há um tempo atrás, fiz um site que usava um `favicon.ico`. Depois disso, já fiz uns 3 sites e o problema ocorre em todos.

Embora eu coloque a URL do `favicon.ico` para uma figura, ele mostra no browser o favicon do site anterior.

Olhando no `Ctr+U` (Código Fonte), e clicando no link que chama o favicon, a figura que abre é a correta. Mas no navegador aparece sempre a errada. E essa imagem nem existe mais na pasta do site.

Já limpei o cache de navegação, depois disso até já formatei o computador e continua esse erro.

Será que pode ser coisa do Chrome salvando isso em "nuvem" semelhante ao que ele faz com os favoritos? Se for, como corrigir?

Comment: Isso é cache, ou o favicon novo foi gravado no formato errado. Se usa <link> para o favicon, simplesmente use nomes diferentes a cada edição e está resolvido. Aliás, nesse caso nem compensa usar o formato .ico, que tem compactação ruim. Deixe um  favicon.ico neutro somente como fallback, para navegadores mais antigos.

Comment: Isso é cache mesmo, comigo eu sempre abro a imagem em outra guia, e depois atualizo a página, a nova imagem aparece...

Comment: to começando a achar que é coisa do google pois nem limpando cache resolve. Testei aqui no firefox e não deu esse problema.

Answer (score 6):

Para forçar a atualização do `favicon`, utilize uma [*query string*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) no nome do seu ficheiro. Por exemplo:

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://www.seusite.com/favicon.ico?v=2" />
```

Isto obriga os navegadores a fazerem download da nova versão do favicon.

> Eu também já tive este mesmo problema em projetos que testava sobre o mesmo domínio, e adicionando a *query string* `?v=2` (ou um número de versão qualquer aleatório) no final da URL no `<link />`, a atualização para a nova versão é feita com êxito! Até o próprio Stack Overflow utiliza esse método.

Comment: Sim, mas isso só ocorro no chrome. Mas vou fazer o que disse e retono.

Answer (score -4):

se seu provedor de internet for local, o cara deve usar cache e você acessa apenas alguns arquivos atuais do seu site online, outros arquivos (como o icone por exemplo), voce acessa a versao armazenada no cache dele.

se for esse o caso, fale com o provedor de internet e peça pra desativarem o cache que vai pra sua máquina